# Using Flowbite and Tailwind, the button to show a modal stays disabled when using modal.hide()

Tags: tailwind-css, flowbite

I am using the button to display a Flowbite modal

```html
<button id="model-but" data-modal-target="extralarge-modal" data-modal-toggle="extralarge-modal" class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded " >
  Create a News Article
</button>
```

The modal code is this (I have removed a lot of the inner code since it is verbose:

```html
<div id="extralarge-modal" tabindex="-1" class="fixed top-0 left-0 right-0 z-50 hidden w-full p-4 overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-auto md:inset-0 h-[calc(100%-1rem)] max-h-full">
  <div class="relative w-full max-w-7xl max-h-full">
    BUNCH of stuff removed
  </div>

  <div class="flex items-center p-4 md:p-5 space-x-3 rtl:space-x-reverse border-t border-gray-200 rounded-b dark:border-gray-600">
    <button id="save-article" type="button" class="bunch removed">Save</button>
    <button data-modal-hide="extralarge-modal" type="button" class="bunch removed">Cancel</button>
  </div>
<div>
```

On the save button, I have removed the `data-modal-hide="extralarge-modal"`.

In my JavaScript I have

```js
const $targetEl = document.getElementById('extralarge-modal');
const modal = new Modal($targetEl);
$('#save-article').click(function(event){
  modal.hide();
});
```

The `modal.hide()` hides the modal, but everything else is still behind the `modal-backdrop` `div`.

What is the correct way to remove it?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating your own instance of the `Modal` class. This would be in **addition** to the one that would automatically be instantiated by Flowbite's JavaScript.

Instead of creating your own `Modal` instance, consider getting the auto-created instance and calling `.hide()` on that:

```js
$('#save-article').click(function() {
  window
    .FlowbiteInstances
    .getInstance('Modal', 'extralarge-modal')
    ?.hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-v2CJ7UaYy4JwqLDIrZUI/4hqeoQieOmAZNXBeQyjo21dadnwR+8ZaIJVT8EE2iyI61OV8e6M8PP2/4hpQINQ/g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/2.2.1/flowbite.min.css" integrity="sha512-75dkJxTte+gUDJlkLYrVF5u55sGUQpYuGiDaMtsSq+jmblR1yBv1QgKNi3vDcjo4E2Nk/7LOYV65Cq8gkfQGJw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/2.2.1/flowbite.min.js" integrity="sha512-khqZ6XB3gzYqfJvXI2qevflbsTvd+aSpMkOVQUvXKyhRgEdORMefo3nNOvCM8584/mUoq/oBG3Vb3gfGzwQgkw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.1.4"></script>

<button id="model-but" data-modal-target="extralarge-modal" data-modal-toggle="extralarge-modal" class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded " >
  Create a News Article
</button>

<div id="extralarge-modal" tabindex="-1" class="fixed top-0 left-0 right-0 z-50 hidden w-full p-4 overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-auto md:inset-0 h-[calc(100%-1rem)] max-h-full">
  <div class="relative w-full max-w-7xl max-h-full">
    BUNCH of stuff removed
  </div>

  <div class="flex items-center p-4 md:p-5 space-x-3 rtl:space-x-reverse border-t border-gray-200 rounded-b dark:border-gray-600">
    <button id="save-article" type="button" class="bunch removed">Save</button>
    <button data-modal-hide="extralarge-modal" type="button" class="bunch removed">Cancel</button>
  </div>
<div>
```